# SharePoint Mail Stop Sending Outgoing Mail

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, sharepoint-email, smtp, outgoing-email

[image: Mail Log]I am trying to configure my SharePoint Mails

Mails were working fine and no settings have changed on the smtp server, receive  an error code 550

Please help.
[image: SMTP Log]

Answer (score 0):

Did the issue occur in SharePoint 2010 or SharePoint 2013?

Did you configure the outgoing mail with office 365?

If the issue exists in SharePoint 2013, then you could check if the outgoing mail is configured correctly according to the article below.

Configure outgoing email for a SharePoint 2013 farm.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263462.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thank you Amy, I have followed this, not sure what I am missing. It is not for office365. Running SharePoint 2016 on premise with a window server 2012 R2. Mails were sending out, just stopped for some reason

Comment: You could check if there is information about the issue in ULS log in SharePoint 2016 server.

Comment: Thank you Amy. any idea what process or product will run the mail sending in the ul log??  Will it be SharePoint Timer Service??